# How can I reduce the number of function expressions?

Tags: javascript, function, declaration, simplify

This code has too many function expressions and I would like to simplify it but I don't know how.

```
(function(a, b) {
    for (a in b = a.prototype)(function(c) {
        b[a] = function() {
            c.apply(this, arguments);
            return this
        }
    })(b[a])
})(Element);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aap7y/

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: This snippet has three function expressions. There are no function declarations.

Comment: @j08691 I figured this would be better suited for stackexange as it is a problem I have and not code I need reviewing

Comment: @williammalo, what kind of problems are you having with the code? How are you using it?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov The problem is that there are too many useless function expressions that I can't get rid of, as for how I use it, check the jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 3):

While the number of times the function syntax is used will be the same, you can reduce the number of functions created by removing the IIFE from the loop, and making it a named function...

```
(function(type) {

    var proto = type.prototype,
        fn;

    function createChainable(proto_func) {
        return function() {
            proto_func.apply(this, arguments);
            return this;
        };
    }

    for (fn in proto)
        proto[fn] = createChainable(proto[fn]);

})(Element);
```

I also got rid of that manual obfuscation. No need for it.

The outer IIFE is just to prevent the global variables. You could get rid of it, but then you end up with global pollution.

If that doesn't bother you, then delete the first and last lines, and replace `type.prototype` with `Element.prototype`.

Comment: The outer function is there to stay, I want to keep the variables local. Ide like to get rid of the middle ones.

Comment: @williammalo: To retain the original prototype method, you need to capture a reference to it in a local variable scope that your new replacement function can use. The only want to create variable scope is with a function *(or using the `with` statement that you removed earlier)*. So I'm afraid that the inner ones will be there to stay.

Comment: ...What's your motivation to have them removed?

Comment: making the code more readable... (I'm ocd like that)

Comment: @williammalo: Yeah, I see what you mean. For me, a big step in readability was removing the inlined function and replacing it with the `createChainable`. If it helps, you can name the anonymous function returned, like `return function proto_replacement() {...`